# XML based, component scanning or @Configuration bean based application context starts up is faster?

Tags: xml, performance, spring, configuration

I work on an application where we use XML and component scanning mixed to define how dependencies should be wired together.

Starting up application takes around one to three seconds, which is more or less OK. However, for functional tests we start it up a few hundred times. You can guess the rest...

I wonder if there is any performance comparison available that compares XML based, component scanning and @configuration bean based spring application context in terms of start up performance.

I'm planning to make a small sandbox project to find out which performs better if I get no answer here for a few days.

Thanks in advance guys.
Tamás

Answer (score 2):

Rather than worrying about which startup config is faster, it might be more effective to look at your test harness.

If the functional tests can all run in the same Spring configuration, then why not just load it once?  The documentation discusses this specific issue: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testing-ctx-management

Reduce the number of times the text context(s) is/are loaded and you will have faster overall testing times.  And if there is some kind of reason why some tests need to have individualized startups, then fine, load them in their own contexts.

Answer (score 1):

At the end I spent 10 minutes and I did a small spike on the topic.

I created a new project (spring templates -> Simple Spring Utility Project) and modified it a little.

In test package I added three test cases.

1. One test case with ClassPathXmlApplicationContext that get location of XML that contained bean definition.
2. One test case with ClassPathXmlApplicationContext that get location of XML that contained one single line:
3. One test case with AnnotationConfigApplicationContext that get a class containing a configuration bean (java equivalent of XML used in first case).

Each test case created application contexts 1000 times.

The results:

1. ~10s
2. ~10s
3. ~6s

That means that @Configuration with AnnotationConfigApplicationContext was around 40% faster than the other two.

I need to note that I don't think this measurement is accurate or precises in any term. Dependency hierarchy was way too simple (one bean only), but I would still expect AnnotationConfigApplicationContext to be the fastest solution from the three.